# What happens if wget runs out of disk space?

Tags: download, disk-space, wget

I'm about to run wget to mirror a large website for offline viewing. I'm worried the site might be too large for my hard drive and my download getting screwed up. Is there any way for me to figure out or estimate the size of the site beforehand? What happens if I run out of space halfway through? Can I free up space and resume?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to figure out or estimate the size of the site beforehand?

Ask the owner of the site, which you need to contact anyway if you're talking about sites that "might be too large for my hard drive", think about their bandwidth for a minute...

> What happens if I run out of space halfway through? Can I free up space and resume?

`wget` has a `--continue` parameter, but whether that works for multiple files is something you could easily check for yourself by faking out of space (aka, do it in a very small tmpfs).

Comment: Check out this [article](https://seogadget.co.uk/download-your-website-with-wget/) and also learn more about [Wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/#download).